# How to create directory in ADLS gen2 from pyspark databricks

Tags: python, azure, pyspark, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2

**Summary**:
I am working on a use-case where i want to write images via cv2 in the ADLS from within pyspark streaming job in databricks, however it doesn't work if the directory doesn't exist.
But i want to store image in specific structure depending on the image attributes.
so basically i need to check at runtime if directory exists or not and create it if it doesn't exist.
Initially I tried using dbutils, but dbutils can't be used inside pyspark api.
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/28070

**Expected Results:**
To be able to able to create directory from within pyspark streaming job in ADLS Gen2
at runtime.

**Reproducible code:**

```
# Read images in batch for simplicity
df = spark.read.format('binaryFile').option('recursiveLookUp',True).option("pathGlobfilter", "*.jpg").load(path_to_source')
```

```
# Get necessary columns

df = df.withColumn('ingestion_timestamp',F.current_timestamp())
.withColumn('source_ingestion_date',F.to_date(F.split('path','/')[10]))
.withColumn('source_image_path',F.regexp_replace(F.col('path'),'dbfs:','/dbfs/')
.withColumn('source_image_time',F.substring(F.split('path','/')[12],0,8))
.withColumn('year', F.date_format(F.to_date(F.col('source_ingestion_date')),'yyyy'))
.withColumn('month', F.date_format(F.to_date(F.col('source_ingestion_date')),'MM'))
.withColumn('day', F.date_format(F.to_date(F.col('source_ingestion_date')),'dd'))
.withColumn('base_path', F.concat(F.lit('/dbfs/mnt/development/testing/'),F.lit('/year='),F.col('year'),
                                 F.lit('/month='),F.col('month'),
                                 F.lit('/day='),F.col('day'))

# function to be called in foreach call          
def processRow(row):
    source_image_path = row['source_image_path']
    base_path = row['base_path']
    source_image_time = row['source_image_time']
    if not CheckPathExists(base_path):
      dbutils.fs.mkdirs(base_path)
    full_path = f"{base_path}/{source_image_time}.jpg"
    im = image=cv2.imread(source_image_path)
    cv2.imwrite(full_path,im)
```

```
# This fails

df.foreach(processRow)

# Due to below code block
if not CheckPathExists(base_path):
  dbutils.fs.mkdirs(base_path)
full_path = f"{base_path}/{source_image_time}.jpg"
im = image=cv2.imread(source_image_path)
cv2.imwrite(full_path,im)
```

Do anyone have any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

**AFAIK**,  `dbutils.fs.mkdirs(base_path)` works for the path like `dbfs:/mnt/mount_point/folder`.

I have reproduced this and when I check the path like `/dbfs/mnt/mount_point/folder` with `mkdirs` function, **the folder is not created in the ADLS even though it gave me `True` in databricks**.

But for `dbfs:/mnt/mount_point/folder` it is working fine.

This might be the issue here. So, first check the path exists or not with this path `/dbfs/mnt/mount_point/folder` and if not then create the directory with `dbfs:/` this path.

**Example:**

```
import os  
base_path="/dbfs/mnt/data/folder1"  
print("before : ",os.path.exists(base_path))

if not os.path.exists(base_path):  
base_path2="dbfs:"+base_path[5:]  
dbutils.fs.mkdirs(base_path2)

print("after : ",os.path.exists(base_path))
```

[image]

You can see the folder is created.

[image]

If you don't want to use `os` directly check if the path exists using the below list and create the directory.

[image]